# FMX rendering issue on both Windows and Android

Tags: firemonkey

Have a simple FMX form with a small image and under 10 standard components (buttons, panels, labels).

There is a considerable delay between the form's onActivate and onPaint. usually on windows about 4 seconds, and Android is completely stuck and never gets to onPaint!

There is no code running between the procs nor execution of threads nor timers.

What could be going on in the background between those 2 processes?

Comment: Cannot reproduce! I made an application with two forms. `Form2` has some standard components (13 to be exact) The time between `OnActivate` and `OnPaint` is 18 ms (yes, milli seconds) on Windows. If you can provide a [mre] that exhibits even a 1 second delay, I will be glad to remove my dv an cv.

Comment: @Tom. thanks.
For whatever reason - after rebooting the system - everything was ok. The old reboot method still applies even with Delphi.

The interesting part is that it also was true for a compiled version (with debug) running outside of the IDE.

I did shut down delphi entirely and tried, perhaps something was still "cached"
The version is 10.3.3 but unsure if it even warrants a report / fix request

Since the event, I was unable to reproduce as well..  
Lets call it a time waster.. drove me nuts for few hours

Comment: Ok, I was pretty sure you would not be able to create a mre. No reason to report anywhere without a mre. Cheers!